# What happens when dereferencing a function that doesn't return?

Tags: c++, pointers, crash, return

```
variableName = pointerName -> getValue();
```

Say that `getValue()` has two routes and only one of them has a return (which is undefined), but it still compiles. What happens if this was in a real time scenario if there was nothing checking or catching this error of no return? Does it crash the program?

Comment: Could you post code so that everyone would understand your question clearly?

Comment: Undefined Behavior. Anything can happen.

Comment: Are you asking us to explain the behavior of undefined behavior?

Comment: I don't think the OP knows what UB is.

Comment: @drescherjm Well the OP says it is undefined so they must know at least a little bit that it is.

Comment: I am brand new to programming. My high school teacher hasn't taught us much. pointerName will be used in alot of the following code and it needs to be specific.

Comment: "_Does it crash the program?_" it can. It can also keep on running and format your drive. Undefined behaviour has no specific result or outcome.

Answer (score 0):

If you "fall off" the end of a function that should return a value, the behaviour is undefined.  That means *anything* can happen.  Typical examples of undefined behaviour:

- The program crashes immediately (this is the best you can possibly hope for)
- The program crashes later in some completely unrelated part of the code
- The program formats your hard drive
- The program causes your monitor to catch fire or explode (this used to be actually possible).
- The program appears to work most of the time, but just occasionally, (typically when demonstrating to MD/important client/professor), it will crash.
- The program will only crash when installed on major customer site and subject to significant load.

Don't try to predict what undefined behaviour will do - anything can happen.